# read a multiline string in python

Tags: python

I need to parse a string and read a particular substring from it. The string I need to parse is as follows :

```
domain
(
    (device
          (console
               (xxxxxx)
               (XXXXXX)
          )
    )
)

domain
(
    (device
          (vfb
               (xxxxxx)
               (location : 5903)
          )
    )
)
```

This is just a sample string. The actual string might contain many such substrings.
I need to get the value of location field just from the "vfb" substring. I tried the findall and search functions as follows

```
import re
text=re.search('(device(vfb(.*?)))',stringname)
```

and

```
import re
text=re.findall('(device(vfb(.*?)))',stringname,re.DOTALL)
```

But I am getting empty string always.
Is there a easy way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: There is a newline between `(device` and `(vfb` that you are ignoring, same after.

Comment: Although this format is hideous, the "right" solution is to write a parser for it, and perhaps translate it to something less ad-hoc such as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just look for `location` key-value pair?

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+) : (\w+)', s)
    [('location', '5903')]
```

Comment: because there might be multiple substrings having location but i want the one under "vfb" sunheading

Answer (score 0):

Simple python script:

```
fp = open("input.txt", "r")

data = fp.readlines()
for line in data:

    if "location" in line:
        print line.split(":")[1].split(")")[0].strip()

fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'device.*?\(vfb.*\(.*\).*(\(.*?\))', s, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: this seems like the most simplistic approach. But unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the correct regular expression.
I tried to modify it but it still doesn't work

Comment: but i run it well,my python is 2.7!