# regular expression for a string format

Tags: python

I have a string as

```
(device
    (vfb
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (location 0.0.0.0:5900)
    )
)

(device
    (console
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (location 80)
    )
)
```

I need to read the location line from "vfb" portion of the string. I have tried to use regular expression like

```
  import re
  re.findall(r'device.*?\vfb.*?\(.*?(.*?).*(.*?\))
```

But it doesn't give me the required output.

Comment: Sounds like a task for pyparsing instead.

Comment: "now you have two problems."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182594/parsing-s-expressions-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [read a multiline string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037183/read-a-multiline-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use a parser for problems like this. Fortunately, a parser would be rather trivial in your case:

```
def parse(source):

    def expr(tokens):
        t = tokens.pop(0)
        if t != '(':
            return {'value': t}
        key, val = tokens.pop(0), {}
        while tokens[0] != ')':
            val.update(expr(tokens))
        tokens.pop(0)
        return {key:val}

    tokens = re.findall(r'\(|\)|[^\s()]+', source)
    lst = []
    while tokens:
        lst.append(expr(tokens))
    return lst
```

Given the above snippet, this creates a structure like:

```
[{'device': {'vfb': {'location': {'value': '0.0.0.0:5900'}, 'xxxxxxxx': {}}}},
 {'device': {'console': {'location': {'value': '80'}, 'xxxxxxxx': {}}}}]
```

Now you can iterate it and fetch whatever you need:

```
for item in parse(source):
    try:
        location = item['device']['vfb']['location']['value']
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

With that intro from Martijn Pieters, here is a pyparsing approach:

```
inputdata = """(device
    (vfb
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (location 0.0.0.0:5900)
    )
)

(device
    (console
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (xxxxxxxx)
        (location 80)
    )
)"""

from pyparsing import OneOrMore, nestedExpr

# a nestedExpr defaults to reading space-separated words within nested parentheses
data = OneOrMore(nestedExpr()).parseString(inputdata)

print (data.asList())

# recursive search to walk parsed data to find desired entry
def findPath(seq, path):
    for s in seq:
        if s[0] == path[0]:
            if len(path) == 1:
                return s[1]
            else:
                ret = findPath(s[1:], path[1:])
                if ret is not None:
                    return ret
    return None
print findPath(data, "device/vfb/location".split('/'))
```

prints:

```
[['device', ['vfb', ['xxxxxxxx'], ['xxxxxxxx'], ['location', '0.0.0.0:5900']]], 
 ['device', ['console', ['xxxxxxxx'], ['xxxxxxxx'], ['location', '80']]]]
0.0.0.0:5900
```

Comment: Nice - here's a tip, I have always thought it clunky to have to define a string with all the characters in printables except for 1 or 2 special punctuation or delimiters. So now instead of having to create your `no_parens` variable, just for the sake of creating a Word of any printable except for left and right parens, you can do `Word(printables,excludeChars='()')`.

Comment: thanks, I've updated [the gist](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4380882/).  I had pyparsing 1.5.2 version where there is no `excludeChars`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gets you started:

```
In [84]: data = '(device(vfb(xxxxxxxx)(xxxxxxxx)(location 0.0.0.0:5900)))'

In [85]: m = re.search(r"""
  .....:     vfb
  .....:     .*
  .....:     \(
  .....:         location
  .....:         \s+
  .....:         (
  .....:             [^\)]+
  .....:         )
  .....:     \)""", data, flags=re.X)

In [86]: m.group(1)
Out[86]: '0.0.0.0:5900'
```